# Template-driven Form - Custom validators

Tags: angular, jhipster

**Goal**

Using JHipster 5.0 and Angular 6.

The value in the input have to be 0,0.5 or 1. I don't want to use a select to force the options because I want the user to be able to type quickly the numbers in each input.

**The form**

```
        <tr  *ngFor="let keyOfMap of keysOfMap ; let i= index" >
                <td> {{keyOfMap}} </td>
                <td *ngFor="let arrayOfArray of arrayOfArrays[i] ; let f = index "  >
                    <form name="editForm" role="form" #editForm="ngForm">
                    <input type= number class = "form-control-plaintext" name="quantite" id="field_quantite" [(ngModel)]="arrayOfArray.quantite" required>
                        <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.quantite?.invalid)">
                            <small class="form-text text-danger"
                                   [hidden]="!editForm.controls.quantite?.errors?.required" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.required">
                                This field is required.
                            </small>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    {{arrayOfArray.quantite}}
                </td>
        </tr>
```

**Issue**

I don't find if an option exist to apply such validator. If it doesn't exist, I don't know how to add it in JHipster/Angular. I don't find the correct informations for now.

**EDIT EDIT**

Ok this works: pattern="(0|0.5|1)"!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what is described in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms) ?

Comment: Hello, I just found a solution. It's in the EDIT part. Thanks!